# Lower the voltage on a 5V PSU to 4.9V

Tags: led, voltage-divider, voltage-clipping

I've been working on a mostly software based project that includes an  addressable LED strip. I am powering the strip with an old ATX PSU and the LEDs seem to be vely unstable when at low brightness. I measured the voltage and at low brightness the voltage is about 5.14V which causes the instability. Under heavier load the voltage drops by 0.2V or so and the LEDs stabilise. Now i am looking for a safe way to lower the voltage to 4.9V. I suspect a simple voltage divider circuit is not suitable due to the fact that the LED strip can consume up to 40W of power. What would be the best way to aproach this?

Note: I have a 300W PSU so efficiency is not as important.

edit:
I am using 144 ws2812b leds and I am powering the microcontroller (esp8266) off of the same PSU, however on a standby power rail

Comment: I think this is an XY problem. What do you mean by "unstable at low brightness"? Does this LED strip allow you to adjust the brightness programatically? What voltage is the LED strip supposed to be powered by (according to the datasheet)?

Comment: It doesn't look like your conclusion that 5.14V "causes instability" is valid, it doesn't make much sense from EE standpoint. What do you mean "LED are very unstable"? It sounds more likely that your 5V source has some stability problem at low load. Why don't you apply a known-good 5 V PSU, or just add a dummy load to your ATX PSU, to make it stable?

Comment: @DanLaks: These are probably LEDs with a built-in addressable dimmer chips. They PWM the LEDs and this is probably causing some instability in the PSU.

Comment: @Transistor, most likely the problem is that ATX PSUs usually need some minimal load, on ANY of its rails, to produce stable outputs. Usually a case 12V-fan is sufficient. The 5V rail might need something like 1 A minimal load.

Comment: @AliChen: It depends. We don't know much about his PSU, if it is a Chinese low end, it can do anything. But vast majority of modern ATX PSU's have that minimum required load included directly in the PSU.

Comment: @AlKepp, all general-purpose ATX12V PSUs are made in China. :-(

Comment: “I measured the voltage and at low brightness the voltage is about 5.14V which causes the instability” Incorrect assumption and clear XY problem. Revisit the problem from a different perspective. How does the signal integrity look? Do you have enough local decoupling? Do you need termination on your data lines?

Comment: cheap ATX PSUs often have minimum load requirements to maintain specified voltages. place a 2-10W dummy load like a power resistor across the rail you need stabilized.

Answer (score 1):

This certainly appears to be an EMI problem.

Without seeing your layout and quality of ground and interference levels of common mode noise, your best bet is to apply a good low ESR decoupling Cap on the LED strips at various lengths and at least at start and end on the 5V rail.  100uF//1uF //0.1uF  low ESR types in this range.

There "may" be interaction between the SMPS f and data pattern at low duty cycles causing the bit errors in 800kbaud "look like instability" but nothing that good LOW ESR caps cannot fix at the load.

Routing of the power and ground so that ground shift does not occur from the LED load current, requires your understanding of current flow or show us the complete layout and power , signal paths.

CM chokes may help.